# Capture One 23 multiple cameras tethering

Tags: image, applescript

Currently I have two cameras wire connected for tethering (Sony ILCE-7SM2 and Sony ILCE-6000). Both works fine individually, I am able to take capture using Command+K and live view is working perfectly fine.

Here's the thing. I want to trigger capture for both cameras. There can be up to 1sec of delay. Manually clicking to switch between the camera just takes too long and doesn't meet the requirement of automation.

I tried a different approach using system event. But I can't find the cameras drop down box/menu to choose and interact with.

Any help is deeply appreciated !

I tried to write a AppleScript script using this idea:
 - first set the active camera to item 1 of cameraList
 - capture
 - set the active camera to item 2 of cameraList
 - capture

But I can't get the list of cameras. The list always shows only the active camera. (count cameraList = 1)

Edit:
Sorry for the late update. I'm providing more details on the application I'm using and the script details

[This is the app UI to choose which camera to use, along with the capture button and session name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShUZv.jpg)

I've recently thought about a different approach. Instead of trying to script to change the camera, I want to use multiple sessions with different cameras and try to script to change sessions then capture sequentially.

[As you can see, each window is a session with different cameras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShUZv.jpg)

I have the option to choose whether to open a new session in a new window or in the same window. As I experimented with applescript, I can only detect two session if I choose to open them in seperate windows

```
tell application "Capture One 23"
     activate 
     set sessionList to every document

     set sessionNames to {}
     repeat with currentDoc in sessionList
            set sessionName to name of current Doc
            set end of sessionName to sessionName
     end repeat
     
     display dialog "Session Name:" & return & return & (sessionNames as text)
end tell
```

I also tried to capture sequentially with these sessions by this script

```
tell application "Capture One 23" 
     activate 
     
     set sessionList to every document
     repeat with i from 1 to count of sessionList
          set currentSession to item i of sessionList
          tell curentSession
               capture
          end tell
     end repeat
end tell
```

It did the capture, but only with the ACTIVE session window, not the other one.

My purpose is to capture sequentially with two cameras, but if I don't enable the option to open a new session as a seperate windows (using 2 sessions in 1 window of Capture One), the sessions have the same camera

Any help is sincerely appreciated !

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve]. At the moment, I have no idea what app you are using or how the menus (that you are trying to interact with) even look.

Comment: What application are you attempting to script?  Image Capture, or something else?

Comment: I have editted the post with more debugging details, forgive me for the late update.